# Reading individual pixels into matrix from an Image

Tags: java, matlab

I am working on a character recognition project using neural networks. 
My first objective is to read those pixels from image where i found any alphabets. I mean if there are three alphabets in an image A, B and C at random places, how i will read the pixel values of A, B and C and store them in matrix ?

Comment: Do you want to read this image into a java program or a matlab program?

Comment: Matlab. I want to process character pixels in matrices, matlab can process matrices more efficiently than java.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear. If you mean that you have image files like A.png, B.png etc. and you want the pixel values in a matrix, you can create an RBG matrix in matlab with

```
image = imread('A.png');
```

This will give you a width-height-3 matrix of RGB values.

---

Thanks for the link to the image, let's try again! :-)

So, assuming you don't want to manually say where each character is, we'll have to find them automatically. To do this, let's convert to black&white, then use [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) to find the pixels of each letter.

```
image = imread('A.png');
ibw = im2bw(image);
C = bwconncomp(image);
boxes = regionprops(C, 'BoundingBox');
letters = cell{26};
for i=1:26
  %get left, top, width, height from boxes(i).BoundingBox
  %I'm not on matlab at the moment, so I don't know exactly how to
  %but it should be quite easy.
  letters{i} = image(left:left+width, top:top+height, :);
end
```

After we find connected components, we get their bounding box using [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html) and put each bounding box in a separate image.

Comment: I have a single image file, image.jpeg, which displays three alphabets A, B and C of different size, on random coordinates. I want to read the pixel values for A, B  and C in a matrix.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this image? Still not really sure what you want.

Comment: http://www.soundonsight.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/alphabet.gif      Now, how will i read pixels in individual matrices for alphabet A B C etc. Also note that letters in the image may be handwritten.

Comment: The code I gave above may not work for handwritten text - it assumes that each letter is connected, so an 'i' with a dot will cause a problem. You'd probably have to use some kind of heuristic to solve this (like, if there are two small connected components, and they are in the area where you expect i to be, then combine them). But this code should be a good start anyway, it will work for the file you showed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
imageA=imread('imageA.jpg');
pixel1=imageA(y,x,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Java, you can first load the image as a BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
```

And then you can get the individual pixel RGB values with:

```
image.getRGB(x, y);
```

You can also use Color object to parse RGB integer value into individual color code.

```
Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y));
int red = color.getRed();
int green = color.getGreen();
int blue = color.getBlue();
```

From this point onward you can do pretty much anything you want. I've worked with the same thing in the past. My recommendation is that you shouldn't make the search space too large by using all the color. Black and white will do also in the beginning.